# Adding a JSON array for styled google maps to php?

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I feel really bad asking this question. If what I'm trying to do isn't possible, please advise.

I'm a graphic/web design student and so far only good at html. I'm using a google maps component and would like to style the maps using the API wizard. As Follows: http://pastebin.com/YsKbyS58

Problem is examples use static html and the component is php based: http://pastebin.com/XrEMmTVJ

Can I inject the JSON array into the PHP file? What would the syntax be like?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps syntax for styling the map is like (with your php script) :

```
// Map creation
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contentmap_<?php echo $owner; ?>_<?php echo $id; ?>'),
        {
                zoom: <?php echo $this->Params->get("zoom", 0); ?>,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.<?php echo $this->Params->get("map_type", "ROADMAP"); ?>,
                styles : [
                    {
                     elementType: "geometry",
                     stylers: [
                          { visibility: "on" },
                          { hue: "#ff8800" }
                     ]
                    },{
                     elementType: "labels",
                     stylers: [
                           { hue: "#ffc300" }
                     ]
                    }
                ]
             });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately this breaks the map. (just white). Something must be conflicting somewhere.

Comment: Hum I miss a `,` before the `styles` key. I've edited my post.

Comment: AH! I did the same mistake, thank you. still no change though

Comment: Corrected another syntax fault on my side (stylez instead of styles) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want to apply those styles to your map? Since what you have posted is really just a static object, you can insert it right into your map options:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contentmap_<?php echo $owner; ?>_<?php echo $id; ?>'),
    {
        zoom: <?php echo $this->Params->get("zoom", 0); ?>,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.<?php echo $this->Params->get("map_type", "ROADMAP"); ?>,
            styles:  [ 
                       { 
                         elementType: "geometry",
                         stylers: [
                           { visibility: "on" },
                           { hue: "#ff8800" }
                         ] 
                       },{ 
                         elementType: "labels",
                         stylers: [
                           { hue: "#ffc300" }
                         ] 
                       } 
                     ]
    });
```

If you mean to make the styles dynamic the PHP tags can replace the values inside the `styles` objects too.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the map stops working. Maybe a conflict with the rest of the component. (NEVER MIND, silly syntax error) No difference in styling though.

Comment: No, it must be my fault then. Let me see and try to fix it.

Comment: Found the problem. I used stylez instead of styles. SOLUTION WORKS! wish I could tick two answers as correct :) Thank you, Heitor

Comment: Good luck with your project :)